Number of Injective Functions such that $f(d)+2f(a)+3f(c)=f(b)$
The number of injective functions $f:\{a,b,c,d\}\to\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,10\}$ such that $2f(a)-f(b)+3f(c)+f(d)=0$
I solved this using different cases e.g.
$f(d)+2f(a)+3f(c)=f(b)$
Set $f(c)=0$ and $f(a)=1$ to get
$f(d)+2=f(b)$
$(f(d),f(b))=(2,4),(3,5),(4,6)......,(8,10)\to7$ cases
Similarly counting all the cases lead me to the answer which is $31$.
Is the best approach for this question or there could be a better solution to it?

I wouldn't call this a better approach necessarily, but maybe it gives you some ideas. Consider the expression $2f(a)-f(b)+3f(c)+f(d)$ with it's corresponding matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$ Then all the solutions of $2f(a)-f(b)+3f(c)+f(d)=0$ are given by the kernel of the matrix which is generated by 3 vectors, namely $(1,2,0,0)$, $(-3,0,2,0)$, $(-1,0,0,2)$ and we can write $$\ker\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=L((1,2,0,0),\;(-3,0,2,0),\;(-1,0,0,2))$$ so the solutions $(f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d))$ are given by linear combinations of the 3 vectors above. We can thus rewrite the basis vectors so that all the vectors have positive entries so
$$L((1,2,0,0),\;(-3,0,2,0),\;(-1,0,0,2))=L((1,2,0,0),\;(0,3,1,0),\;(0,1,0,1))$$ from which it follows that
$$(f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d))= \mu(1,2,0,0)+\lambda(0,3,1,0)+\sigma(0,1,0,1)$$ for arbitrary $\mu,\lambda,\sigma \in \mathbb{Z}$.
From here you can somewhat start trying to find the solutions although I'll admit, it's nothing more than brute force from here but here's maybe an approach to finding them a bit more quickly.
Requirements:

$f$ is injective so the 4 coordinates of the vector $(f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d))$ (which are given by linear combinations of the vectors shown above) need to be different.
$f$ must map to your codomain so the $f$ evaluated at $a,b,c,d$ need to be between 0 and 10 (inclusive).

Restrictions:
Restriction 1:
The trick to writing the basis vector with positive entries is to note that each vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ occupies one entry on its own. What I mean is that $(1,2,0,0)$ is the only vector with a non-zero first entry, $(0,3,1,0)$ is the only vector with a non-zero third entry and $(0,1,0,1)$ is the only vector with a non-zero fourth entry. Therefore, any arbitrary solution given by $$(f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d))= \mu(1,2,0,0)+\lambda(0,3,1,0)+\sigma(0,1,0,1)$$ for $\mu,\lambda,\sigma \in \mathbb{Z}$, must have $\mu,\lambda,\sigma \geq 0$ since otherwise one of the $f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d)$ will be negative, which is not in your codomain.
Restriction 2:
The second restriction is an upper bound on  $\mu,\lambda,\sigma$. Since $f(a),f(b),f(c),f(d)$ are at maximum 10. It follows that $\mu \leq 5$, $\lambda \leq 3$ and $\sigma \leq 10$.
That's all I have I guess.
To be honest, now that I've finished writing this, I don't actually know if this is more or less efficient than simply counting them as you did, but I guess it is a different approach nonetheless.

(Echoing your final statement) I don't see how this furthers our understanding of the problem. You've rephrased it, but not yet in a way that could help us make the count. FWIW See my approach.

Rephrase the problem to:

Find the number of pairwise distinct ordered triples $(A, C, D) \in [0, 10]^3$ such that $2A + 3C + D \leq 10$.
(Furthermore, show that $B = 2A+3C+D$ is distinct from $A, C, D$. )

Main idea: We apply PIE directly. We count all solutions with no restriction, then subtract those where a pair of variables are equal, add back those where 2 pairs of variables are equal, and subtract those where 3 pairs of variables are equal.
To count each case, I use generating functions for its simplicity, but you're welcome to use any method that you want.

Without any restrictions:

We want the sum of coefficients of the first 11 terms of $(1 + x^2 +  x^4 + \ldots x^{20} ) ( 1 + x^3 + x^6 + \ldots + x^{30} ) ( 1+ x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{10}$).
Since we only care when exponents are $\leq 10$, we can add in larger exponents and write this as $ \frac{ 1}{1-x^2} \frac{1}{1 -x^3 } \frac{1}{1-x} $, and expand to get $ 1 + x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 + 5x^5 + 7x^6 + 8x^7 + 10 x^8 + 12x^9 + 14x^{10}$, for total of 67 solutions.


If $A = C$

We want the sum of coefficients of the first 11 terms of $(1 + x^5 + x^{10} + \ldots x^{50} )  ( 1+ x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{10}$).
This is easy to multiply out to get $ 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + 2x^5 + 2x^6 + 2x^7 + 2x^8 + 2x^9 + 3x^{10}$ for a total of 18 solutions.


If $ A = D$

We want the sum of coefficients of the first 11 terms of $(1 + x^3 +  x^{6} + \ldots x^{30} )  ( 1+ x^3 + x^6+ \ldots + x^{30})$.
This is easy to multiply out to get $ 1 + 2x^3 + 3x^6 + 4x^9 $ for a total of 10 solutions.


If $ C = D$

We want the sum of coefficients of the first 11 terms of $(1 + x^2 +  x^{4} + \ldots x^{20} )  ( 1+ x^4 + x^8+ \ldots + x^{40})$.
Use either method to get $ 1 + x^2 + 2x^4 + 2x^6 + 3x^8 + 3x^{10}$ for a total of 12 solutions.


If $ A = C = D$

Clearly there are 2 solutions.


Hence by PIE, the number of solutions is
$$ 67 - (18+10+12)  + (2+2+2) - 2 = 31, $$
as claimed by OP.

